# How to copy a file in a particular directory without knowing the end name, from a docker container (glob not working)

Tags: docker

I have a directory and the end of the its name changes. I would like to be able to copy the file contained in this directory. For example, I have this path (I don't know what the directory name is after `-`, here this example it is `ab`) :

```
/tmp/folder-ab/file
```

I would like to copy the file.

This works outside of docker:

```
cp /tmp/folder-*/file /other/path/
```

But I want to copy from a docker container, so I tried:

```
 docker cp $CONTAINERID:/tmp/[folder-]*/file /other/path/
```

and I got the following error :

```
Error response from daemon: lstat
 /var/lib/docker/100000.100000/devicemapper/mnt/1ae07ffeda9e69465058ad01439543ab17a142d74668350b9185c1632cd7dec7/rootfs/tmp/folder-*/file:
 no such file or directory
```

Comment: I assume what you tried did not work. What is the problem with `cp /tmp/folder-*/file /other/path` ? Any error messages ?

Comment: Did that first example with `folder-*` not work? Is `$CONTAINERID` supposed to part of the path?

Comment: The first example work but I would like to use it in a docker container

Comment: Please be clear, in the question (you can edit it), about what worked, and what did not.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I can't make it work with the copy function docker

Comment: @executable please click [edit] to enhance your original question with the information we need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why it does not work

In your code `docker cp $CONTAINERID:/tmp/[folder-]*/file /other/path` you use a glob (`*`). Globs are expanded by the shell, but your shell does not know about the files in the container. Your current configuration of your shell, is to leave the `*` in the file name, as if just a normal character. Docker then tells you that `…/folder-*/…` can not be found.

## What to do

These are untested, please test.

```
files="$(docker exec «container» bash -c "echo /folder-*/file")" #does not deal with spaces, etc.
do something with "$files"
```

or

```
docker exec «container» bash -c 'for f in *; do printf "%s\0" "$f"; done' | \
xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty cp -t "/other/path"
```

Comment: ... which means `sh -c 'cp .../folder-*/file ...'` may possibly work, but I don't know Docker well enough to say anythig about that `$CONTAINERID` stuff in the source path.

Comment: @Kusalananda `docker cp` is a command, it does not mean run `cp` in docker. But you are onto something. You can do `docker exec «container» «command», but you may not have access to all of host file system. You could use it to get some info.

Comment: So, there is no way to do it ?

Comment: There are many ways, but I have not mentioned them: It is only the globing that is not working, so you could do a `docker exec «container» bash -c "…./folder-*/file…"` to get the list.

Comment: How can I know if the file exist ? I need something like `FOUND=$(docker exec «container» bash -c "ls /folder-*/file")`. `$FOUND` should be 1 or 0

Comment: I have added to answer. Note variable should not be capitals (capitals is for environment variables). And parsing the output of `ls` will usually lead to problems.

Comment: Good to know,I always use capital in my variable